# Comparing two array columns in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, subset, array-column

I have a dataframe of format given below.

```
movieId1 | genreList1              | genreList2
--------------------------------------------------
1        |[Adventure,Comedy]       |[Adventure]
2        |[Animation,Drama,War]    |[War,Drama]
3        |[Adventure,Drama]        |[Drama,War]
```

and trying to create another flag column which shows whether genreList2 is a subset of genreList1.

```
movieId1 | genreList1              | genreList2        | Flag
---------------------------------------------------------------
1        |[Adventure,Comedy]       | [Adventure]       |1
2        |[Animation,Drama,War]    | [War,Drama]       |1
3        |[Adventure,Drama]        | [Drama,War]       |0
```

I have tried this:

```scala
def intersect_check(a: Array[String], b: Array[String]): Int = {
  if (b.sameElements(a.intersect(b))) { return 1 } 
  else { return 2 }
}

def intersect_check_udf =
  udf((colvalue1: Array[String], colvalue2: Array[String]) => intersect_check(colvalue1, colvalue2))

data = data.withColumn("Flag", intersect_check_udf(col("genreList1"), col("genreList2")))
```

But this throws error

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function.

P.S.: The above function (`intersect_check`) works for `Array`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can define an `udf` that calculates the length of the `intersection` between the two `Array` columns and checks whether it is equal to the length of the second column. If so, the second array is a subset of the first one.

Also, the inputs of your `udf` need to be class `WrappedArray[String]`, not `Array[String]` :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val same_elements = udf { (a: WrappedArray[String], 
                           b: WrappedArray[String]) => 
  if (a.intersect(b).length == b.length){ 1 }else{ 0 }  
}

df.withColumn("test",same_elements(col("genreList1"),col("genreList2")))
  .show(truncate = false)
+--------+-----------------------+------------+----+
|movieId1|genreList1             |genreList2  |test|
+--------+-----------------------+------------+----+
|1       |[Adventure, Comedy]    |[Adventure] |1   |
|2       |[Animation, Drama, War]|[War, Drama]|1   |
|3       |[Adventure, Drama]     |[Drama, War]|0   |
+--------+-----------------------+------------+----+
```

**Data**

```
val df = List((1,Array("Adventure","Comedy"), Array("Adventure")),
              (2,Array("Animation","Drama","War"), Array("War","Drama")),
              (3,Array("Adventure","Drama"),Array("Drama","War"))).toDF("movieId1","genreList1","genreList2")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution converting using `subsetOf`

```
  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
    (1,Array("Adventure","Comedy"),Array("Adventure")),
  (2,Array("Animation","Drama","War"),Array("War","Drama")),
  (3,Array("Adventure","Drama"),Array("Drama","War"))
  )).toDF("movieId1", "genreList1", "genreList2")


  val subsetOf = udf((col1: Seq[String], col2: Seq[String]) => {
    if (col2.toSet.subsetOf(col1.toSet)) 1 else 0
  })

  data.withColumn("flag", subsetOf(data("genreList1"), data("genreList2"))).show()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 3.0+** (**[`forall`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#forall(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)**)

```scala
forall($"genreList2", x => array_contains($"genreList1", x)).cast("int")
```

---

Full example:

```scala
val df = Seq(
     (1, Seq("Adventure", "Comedy"), Seq("Adventure")),
     (2, Seq("Animation", "Drama","War"), Seq("War", "Drama")),
     (3, Seq("Adventure", "Drama"), Seq("Drama", "War"))
     ).toDF("movieId1", "genreList1", "genreList2")

val df2 = df.withColumn("Flag", forall($"genreList2", x => array_contains($"genreList1", x)).cast("int"))

df2.show()
// +--------+--------------------+------------+----+
// |movieId1|          genreList1|  genreList2|Flag|
// +--------+--------------------+------------+----+
// |       1| [Adventure, Comedy]| [Adventure]|   1|
// |       2|[Animation, Drama...|[War, Drama]|   1|
// |       3|  [Adventure, Drama]|[Drama, War]|   0|
// +--------+--------------------+------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to exploit spark array builtin functions: `genreList2` is subset of `genreList1` if the intersection between the two is equal to `genreList2`. In the code below a `sort_array` operation has been added to avoid a mismatch between two arrays with different ordering but same elements.

```
val spark = {
    SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("test")
    .getOrCreate()
}

import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
    (1, Array("Adventure","Comedy"), Array("Adventure")),
    (2, Array("Animation","Drama","War"), Array("War","Drama")),
    (3, Array("Adventure","Drama"), Array("Drama","War"))
).toDF("movieId1", "genreList1", "genreList2")

df
.withColumn("flag",
 sort_array(array_intersect($"genreList1",$"genreList2"))
 .equalTo(
   sort_array($"genreList2")
 )
.cast("integer")
)
.show()
```

The output is

```
+--------+--------------------+------------+----+
|movieId1|          genreList1|  genreList2|flag|
+--------+--------------------+------------+----+
|       1| [Adventure, Comedy]| [Adventure]|   1|
|       2|[Animation, Drama...|[War, Drama]|   1|
|       3|  [Adventure, Drama]|[Drama, War]|   0|
+--------+--------------------+------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work here and it does not use udf

```
 import spark.implicits._
 val data = Seq(
        (1,Array("Adventure","Comedy"),Array("Adventure")),
        (2,Array("Animation","Drama","War"),Array("War","Drama")),
        (3,Array("Adventure","Drama"),Array("Drama","War"))
      ).toDF("movieId1", "genreList1", "genreList2")

 data
     .withColumn("size",size(array_except($"genreList2",$"genreList1")))
     .withColumn("flag",when($"size" === lit(0), 1) otherwise(0))
     .show(false)
```