# How to Identify the intersection between two Arrays in Scala Spark?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have four arrays that contain the column names from four data frames.

```
var col1 = df1.columns
var col2 = df2.columns
var col3 = df3.columns
var col4 = df4.columns
```

They are all Array[String] . Now the problem is to identify those columns that are commonly occurring in all 4 arrays and those which are not . 
I guess one can start with thinking of finding the intersection of two Arrays and then loop it. Any ideas ? Can we extend this to N dimensional arrays.

So the idea is not just identify intersection across two arrays but multiple arrays and also identify the difference

Comment: Not really a duplicate of that question - the OP seems to be interested in intersecting the _column names_, not their actual values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two array columns in Scala Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158623/comparing-two-array-columns-in-scala-spark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a List of these arrays, and use `reduce` with the `intersect` function:

```
List(col1, col2, col3, col4).reduce((a, b) => a intersect b)
```